# Select timestamp interval of 2 weeks / days

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp

Table: `donate`

Columns: `donate_id, donate_active, donate_time`

`donate_time` value is a `unix_timestamp`

I have to select all entries 2 weeks before reaching the donate_time, to send a reminder email.

I tried many ways, but I always get a syntax error.

```
SELECT * FROM donate 
WHERE donate_time >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK))
```

Comment: `but I always get a syntax error.`  Go on...

Comment: I am not sure, but should be interval 2 weeks single quoted?

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WEEK))

Comment: @McNets - nope, see here:  http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_date_sub.asp

Comment: @labu77 - not related to your initial problem, but I think you want Date_Add, and you want `<=` not `>=`

Comment: @Joe I think so as well, though I can't spot a syntax error.

Comment: it works in restexter http://rextester.com/DIAZ24305

Comment: @labu77 - We give up... what was the syntax error that you got???

Comment: Could you post some records from donate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/functions/date_sub.php) page, `INTERVAL` only supports `WEEK` from version 5, and you said you are running 4.1. Try `14 DAY` instead of `2 WEEK`.

Answer (score 1):

I pasted your code and it works for me in MySQL Workbench 5.2.47.

Make sure you have a space after the table name and a semicolon at the end.

Check any surrounding code for sytax errors.

Here is the code I ran successfully.  Try pasting back to your environment (change names).

```
SELECT * FROM requests 
WHERE returntime >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK))
```

Comment: I have SQL Server Version: 4.1, with 5.2 it works perfect. Is there a way for 4.1?   I know its old but its a dedicated server